# double click to forward output to transaction

Tags: abap, sap-erp, dynpro

I have made a program which outputs a list of equipment numbers using `WRITE`. The transaction `IE03` lets the user input an equipment number, execute, and then displays a whole bunch of information on that piece of equipment.

What I would like to do is be able to double click on one of the numbers my program outputs, and then have the data display that `IE03` would offer.

How do I integrate my custom program with the standard display functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the advice which gave **vwegert**, or:

```
REPORT  ztest.

CONSTANTS:
  gc_equpment_view_tcode TYPE sytcode VALUE 'IE03'.

DATA:
      gt_eqkt TYPE TABLE OF eqkt,
      gs_eqkt TYPE eqkt.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  SELECT * INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_eqkt FROM eqkt
  JOIN equi ON ( equi~equnr EQ eqkt~equnr ) UP TO 10 ROWS
  WHERE eqkt~spras EQ sy-langu.

END-OF-SELECTION.
  LOOP AT gt_eqkt INTO gs_eqkt.
    WRITE: / gs_eqkt-equnr, gs_eqkt-eqktx.
    HIDE: gs_eqkt-equnr.
  ENDLOOP.


AT LINE-SELECTION. 
  CALL FUNCTION 'AUTHORITY_CHECK_TCODE' " check S_TCODE auth. object
    EXPORTING
      tcode  = gc_equpment_view_tcode
    EXCEPTIONS
      ok     = 1
      not_ok = 2
      OTHERS = 3.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 1.
    SET PARAMETER ID 'EQN' FIELD gs_eqkt-equnr.
    "check I_TCODE auth. object (see IE03 definition)
    CALL TRANSACTION gc_equpment_view_tcode AND SKIP FIRST SCREEN.
  ENDIF.
```

Comment: fiddling around with alv for 2 hours trying to get it to work. Then you just come along with 3 bloody lines of code that do exactly what I needed and no previous modifications needed. <3

Comment: While this is the correct answer to your question, it will be worth your while to also get the ALV solution proposed by @vwegert to work.  ALV is a much more relevant technology, and considerably more user-friendly.

Comment: If you want to stay in stone age, do go on, I won't stop you.

Comment: This implementation is a very good example on how NOT to build your software - it bypasses the `S_TCODE` authorization check.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use `WRITE` to create lists - this is stone-age technology. Store your data in an internal table based on a dictionary structure, then use the SALV library to create a list. Take a look at the sample program `SALV_DEMO_TABLE_EVENTS` to see how to display a list and react to a double click. Note that you can throw away much of the demo program because it shows quite a lot of different functions.

Then, you don't "forward" anything to a transaction. You can call a transaction using the ABAP statement `CALL TRANSACTION` (which should be obvious), and you can even pass some values using a crooked mix of SPA/GPA parameters and the addition `... AND SKIP FIRST SCREEN`. Be aware that this only works for certain kinds of transactions and only if they were programmed to do so. For this, you need to store the equipment number in a global variable using

```
SET PARAMETER ID 'EQN' FIELD l_my_equipment_number.
```

and then call the transaction

```
CALL TRANSACTION 'IE03' AND SKIP FIRST SCREEN.
```

**Be aware that this statement does not perform the default authorization checks - if you need to do so, use the function module `AUTHORITY_CHECK_TCODE` as specified by the keyword documentation.**